# Azure cli query Metrics (hostname, CPU, sockets..)

Tags: azure, azure-cli

for our subscription I need a table / list  with
Metrics like hostname, OS, CPU, sockets, cores ..) for  virtual or dedicated azure server (about 7 Server) with Database Software.
I started with the cli
az vm list -d
or I take the portal and create a csv file :-)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope this should help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-monitor#get-metrics---azure-cli

Comment: Thanks - good hint - but I need only static metrics - setup of the server